# Android get URI of assets folder

Tags: android, gallery

I am trying to make a simple gallery from an asset folder in my app.
so I created an asset folder, and created inside a directory called 'pics' and put some jpg files inside.

Then I did this to get all the images from the pics inside the assets folder. I wanted to get it by the URI of the assets folder but it's not working, I guess because the URI is wrong:

```
Uri uriExternal = Uri.parse(getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets().open("pics").toString());
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED };

        Cursor cursorExternal = getContentResolver().query(uriExternal, projection, "bucket_display_name = \""+album_name+"\"", null, null);
        Cursor cursor = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[]{cursorExternal});
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));
            album = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));

            imageList.add(Function.mappingInbox(album, path, null));
        }
```

Comment: `MediaStore` has no idea about your app's assets. Also, there is no official `Uri` to assets, and the unofficial one (`file://android_asset/...`) is for individual asset files.

Comment: @CommonsWare so any idea how can I do it with a folder inside the regular drawable folder?

Comment: Your assets folder has no URI because it's compiled into the APK. There's no direct filesystem access to it.

Comment: @TheWanderer so how can I do it in a different way? if I put the images in drawable folder?

Comment: You don't need URIs to display a collection of images. Just use `[getAssets()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets())`.

Comment: And all resources are also in the APK, so they don't have URIs either.

Comment: `MediaStore` does not know anything about your app's drawables, either. Since your data is baked into your app, I'm not certain why you are fussing with `MediaStore` in the first place. You're hardcoding the images, so hardcode the "album" as well.

Comment: @TheWanderer can you please add a code example how should I change my code then? because right now it is based on the URIs of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
AssetManager assets = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets();
String[] pics = assets.list("pics");
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<>();

for (String path : pics) {
    bmps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assets.open(path));
}
```

The `bmps` list now contains all the images in your `pics` folder as Bitmaps.

I wrote this purely from documentation, and I haven't tested it. I recommend you read the documentation yourself if you run into trouble: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager